# Empty $_REQUEST despite given URL parameters

Tags: php, url, parameters, request

If searched through stackoverflow yet i'm not able to find a solution! 
First of all a small description on how our backend is operating..

The index.php is a pretty big `<form>` in which every subpage will be `required_once`. We've created a module that shows something like a "treeview".
This tree is made up of multiple `<a>` Tags.

Imagine having a node Called "Maintenance".. This node has multiple subnodes.
Like:

`Maintenance
   Server1
   Server2
   ...`

Clicking on Server1 would create a link like:

```php
.../treelistner.php?NODE=temperature_10&ACTIVE=TRUE&SERVER_ID=10&SERVER_NAME=RANDOM
```

Every link refers to the main node "Maintenance" in which i'd like to use the given parameters `SERVER_ID` & `SERVER_NAME` like so:

```php
if(!empty($_REQUEST['SERVER_NAME']))
{
    $oTemperature->SetServerName($_REQUEST['SERVER_NAME']);
}
```

But $_REQUEST is always empty..

Using $_GET or $_POST does not change the result. All are empty.

Any tips on debugging the problem? In a similar module it works this way.. I'm pretty frustrated right now.

Comment: This sounds to be related to the web server, not PHP. Ensure that server is handling the request data properly.

Comment: So to sum it up, when clicking on the link you provided, $_GET,$_POST,$_REQUEST are empty

Comment: @MosesSchwartz yes. print_r($_REQUEST) = Array()

Comment: @Rehmat ive got no access to the server. And this cant be the reason because every other module works the same.

Comment: Is this a link you click or this is the link you are putting in `require()`?

Comment: @MosesSchwartz this is the link i click

Comment: Do you see the URL parameters in the location bar when you click on the link?

Comment: @Barmar yes i do

Comment: Then the problem is on the server somewhere. Maybe there's a rewrite rule that removes the parameters for that URL.